# How to publish mbtiles with mapproxy?

Tags: mbtiles, mapproxy

I have a mbtiles file and want to publish it as wms. My config:

```
services:
  demo:
  wms:
    srs: ['EPSG:3857']
    image_formats: ['image/png']

layers:
   - name: my_layer
     title: WMS layer from tiles
     sources: [mbtiles_cache]

caches:
  mbtiles_cache:
    sources: []
    grids: [GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR]
    cache:
      type: mbtiles
      filename: D:/dev/mbtiles/export/vtagil.mbtiles
```

But I don't see anything in demo or QGIS.

What have I missed?

Comment: You should try to generate zoom levels before you using mapproxy. You can use gdal2tiles.

Comment: My mistake was that i generate mbtiles in my local srs. But when i did same in epsg3857 i got my mbtiles on the map.